# javascript: window.location.hash returns empty string

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a vanilla js recipe project that is part of a course.i used the model controller view code pattern and for some reason when i try to get the hash of my current page it returns `<empty string>`.the hash should be a '#'symbol followed by an id of numbers for each recipe.

the code:
controller module:
this async function is where i get the page id

```
import * as model from './model';

const controlRecipe = async function () {
  try {
    const id = window.location.hash.slice(1);
    console.log(id);//logs <empty string>
    
    if (!id) return;

    //loading recipe
    await model.loadRecipe(id);//passing the id here

    //rendering recipe
    recipeView.render(model.state.recipe);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

model module:
the id is passed to this loadRecipe function from the controller to load the recipe
the `API_URL` is just the API link without the id
the `getJSON` function gets the json() format of the fetch and then the recipe data is manipulated

```
import { API_URL} from "./config";
import { getJSON } from "./helpers";

export const loadRecipe = async function(id){
    try {
        const data = await getJSON(`${API_URL}${id}`);

        const {recipe} = data.data;

        state.recipe = {
        id: recipe.id,
        title: recipe.title,
        publisher: recipe.publisher,
        sourceUrl: recipe.source_url,
        image: recipe.image_url,
        servings: recipe.servings,
        cookingTime: recipe.cooking_time,
        ingredients: recipe.ingredients,
        };
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

example:
[the id appears at the url but  is logged to the console. when i manually add the '#' it works fine and the id is logged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bknx8.png)

i tried searching for a solution but couldn't find anything. can u please help thanks.

Comment: `location.hash` is for part after `#`. On your screenshot id is just part of `location.pathname`, not hash

Comment: i get that but why is it logged as an empty string, that's what confuses me. and also when i remove the slice method to include the `#` it also logs an empty string

Comment: Because if there is no #fragment in the URL that you used to load your JS, so `window.location.hash` is an empty string? (on which note: `hash` is a string, there is nothing to slice. Did you mean `.substring(1)`?)

Comment: @OlegWock note that it's not, though: `location.hash`, if there is a URL hash, includes the `#`. If there is _no_ hash, it's an empty string.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans strings do support `slice` just fine, `substring` is more or less the same (with different edge case handling)

Comment: Sure, but `slice` is typically associated with arrays, with `substring` associated with strings, so when you see someone show code that uses slice, anyone who works with JS on the daily will assume that this person thinks they're working with an array. Which `hash` isn't.